# how to set via or server name in magento in all emails

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

for example my website is url is www.xyz.com and it is hosted on a company server url is www.abcd.com . when i tried to place order then i am  getting in email  via  abcd.com. i am using WHM cpanel.how  i can set  via xyz.com in email.
please help me[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `System > Configuration` then you will see `General Tab` on left sidebar.

Now click on `Store Email Address`

And set your email address as required.

[image]

Comment: i had set  that setting    but i got via host name why

Comment: suppose i am changing sales email  as  custom@gmail.co then i am getting custom@gmail.com via  host abcd.com

Comment: It might be related to email hosting. You may want to contact them. I don't think it is related to magento.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using your severs mail program ( postfix, sendmail etc ) or are you using an external SMTP server.

I encountered the same issue with the while sending mail through an external SMTP server (mandrill).

I was able to fix my sender addresses by adding DKIM keys generated by mandrill to my dns data

Comment: no  i am  not using  these

Comment: for an example i  had tried  a mail function  in php on that server that time  i  am also getting same  problem

Comment: the php mail() function uses the servers MTA ( mail transfer agent ) ie. postfix, sendmail, exim, courier etc. Postfix for instance has the posibility to relay email to an external smtp server. This usually is the cause for the "strange" sender addresses because your sending mail from server a through  server b to (recieving) server c. If you have configured the server yourself or you can access the MTA config please check your mail settings. If you cant, please contact your hosting provider and ask them how mail is send from their servers.

Comment: You could also try sending a mail from the server to an address generated by this : http://www.mail-tester.com/ website. This will give you an email score and tell you what you are missing. Most likely it will tell you to add a DKIM key :). If indeed you are relaying email it should fix your problem.

Comment: could you explain  it  !!  is it  server hosting problem or magento  problem. one thing  i want  to  know   what is return type  in mail

Comment: problem have resolved  :) i have setup  return type yes from magento admin panel its working  now